# How to fix PHP form validator error?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation, validationerror

Validation of my PHP form is not working. Here is the code that I used in my form. The data is storing in `DB` but validation alone not working. After submitting the form I checked the error console, its simply showing `Type Error document.getElementById('..')null`.

I don't know what it is and how to fix this error. I am new in this php field so don't mind my mistakes.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function art_category()
 {

    document.getElementById('halloween_website_directory1').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('hallo_web_name1').style.display = "none"; 

    document.getElementById('hallo_web_desc1').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('hallo_web_tags1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('msgpost1').style.display = "none";



    if(document.getElementById('halloween_website_directory').value=="")
    {
      document.getElementById('halloween_website_directory1').style.display = "block"; 
      return false;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('hallo_art_name').value=="")
    {
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_name1').style.display = "block"; 

      return false;
    }

    else if(document.getElementById('hallo_art_desc').value=="")
    {
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_desc1').style.display = "block"; 
      return false;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('hallo_art_tags').value=="")
    {
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_tags1').style.display = "block"; 
      return false;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('msgpost').value=="")
    {
      document.getElementById('msgpost1').style.display = "block"; 
      return false;
    }

    else {
    document.artcategory.submit();
     return true;
    }
   }
  </script>
<form name="artcategory" id="artcategory" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return art_category();">
    <table align="center" width="69%" height="75%" border="0" bordercolor="#663300";>
        <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
            <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Select Category:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></p>
            </td>
            <td width="67%" height="60%">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="halloween_website_directory" id="halloween_website_directory">
                            <option value="">Select Website Category</option>
                            <?PHP
                                  $web_cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM halloween_website_directory ORDER BY web_cat_name;");
                                  while($cat = mysql_fetch_array($web_cat))
                                  {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?PHP echo $cat['web_cat_id'] ?>"><?PHP echo $cat['web_cat_name'] ?></option>
                            <?PHP } ?>
                        </select>
                        <span id="halloween_website_directory1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Select Category</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
            <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Article Title:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></p>
            </td>
            <td width="67%" height="60%">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="hallo_art_name" id="hallo_art_name"/>
                        <span id="hallo_art_name1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Please enter the title of your Article</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
               <TD align="center" WIDTH="33%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><P><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Article Description:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></P>
               </TD>
               <TD WIDTH="68%"><P>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<FONT SIZE="-2" FACE="Verdana" color="#FFCC66">&nbsp;Max 300 Characters<BR>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<TEXTAREA NAME="hallo_art_desc" id="hallo_art_desc" ROWS=5 COLS=33 WRAP="virtual"></TEXTAREA>
         <span id="hallo_art_desc1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Enter Description</span>
                                             <BR>
                                                </FONT> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<FONT SIZE="-2" FACE="Verdana" COLOR="#FFCC66"> Do not use "See web site" as
                                                  your description.</FONT></P>
          </TD>
      </TR>

      <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
                <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Article tags:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></p>
                </td>
                <TD WIDTH="68%"><P><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana" color="#FFFFFF">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="hallo_art_tags" id="hallo_art_tags" value="" size=30>
    <span id="hallo_art_tags1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Article Tags</span>
      </FONT><FONT SIZE="-2" FACE="Verdana" color="#FFCC66"><br>
      <font>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Use a comma to separate each
    keyword.</font><BR>
          </FONT></P>
                </TD>
        </tr>

        <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
            <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Article Body:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></p>
            </td>
            <td width="67%" height="60%">
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<textarea name="msgpost" id="msgpost" rows="10"/></textarea>
         <span id="msgpost1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Enter the Article content</span>    
          </td>
        </tr>



        <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
             <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Agree
                                              to our Submission
                                              Policy</font></p></Td>
                                            <TD WIDTH="68%"><P><FONT SIZE="-2" FACE="Verdana">
                                              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="policy" VALUE="Y" CHECKED>
                                            </FONT></P></TD>
                                          </TR>

        <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
            <td align="center" colspan="3" width="67%" height="60%">
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="add_article" id="add_article" value="Submit Article"/>      
            </td>
        </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('')` is a function. It is such an overhead to call the function each time you want to change some properties. Create variables `var msg_post = document.getElementById('msg_post1');` and use them `msg_post.style.value = "asd";`

Comment: where i should use msg_post.style.value = "asd"; ?

Comment: posting a bunch of code .. and asking fix my error will not bring you far. Try to clean up the example first make a form with 1 field and 1 button, make it work, add another type of field, make it work and so on :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many elements in your scripts which does not exists in your HTML. For example, hallo_web_name1, hallo_art_name, hallo_web_desc1 etc. and this is the reason, you are getting this error.

If these elements appear in your HTML code based on some condition, then first check whether they exists, and if yes, then fetch their value as below

```
if (document.getElementById('hallo_web_name1'))
     document.getElementById('hallo_web_name1').style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Yeah, negate usage of variables

Comment: I used those element in the html form span id eg: <span id="hallo_art_name1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Please enter the title of your Article</span>

Comment: If its wrong means how can i use those elements? please help me because i don't have knowledge in this field and i'm have been studying for few weeks only..

Comment: As I said, you do not have all elements in your HTML which you are using in your javascript, to be specific, element "hallo_web_name1" but there are still more. If they are not required, then remove them

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
function art_category()
{

    document.getElementById('halloween_website_directory1').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('hallo_art_name1').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('hallo_art_desc1').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('hallo_art_tags1').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('msgpost1').style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById('chkbox').style.display = "none"; 



    if(document.getElementById('halloween_website_directory').value==""){
      document.getElementById('halloween_website_directory1').style.display = "block"; 
      return false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById('hallo_art_name').value==""){
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_name1').style.display = "block"; 
      return false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById('hallo_art_desc').value==""){
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_name1').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_desc1').style.display = "block"; 
      return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('hallo_art_tags').value==""){
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_name1').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_desc1').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_tags1').style.display = "block"; 
      return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('msgpost').value==""){
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_name1').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_desc1').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_tags1').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('msgpost1').style.display = "block"; 
      return false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById('policy').checked == false){
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_name1').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_desc1').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('hallo_art_tags1').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('msgpost1').style.display = "none"; 
      document.getElementById('chkbox').style.display = "block"; 
      return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="artcategory" id="artcategory" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return art_category();">
  <table align="center" width="69%" height="75%" border="0" bordercolor="#663300";>
    <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
      <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Select Category:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></p></td>
      <td width="67%" height="60%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select name="halloween_website_directory" id="halloween_website_directory">
          <option value="">Select Website Category</option>
          <?PHP $web_cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM halloween_website_directory ORDER BY web_cat_name;");
                while($cat = mysql_fetch_array($web_cat)){
           ?>
          <option value="<?PHP echo $cat['web_cat_id'] ?>"><?PHP echo $cat['web_cat_name'] ?></option>
          <?PHP } ?>
        </select>
        <span id="halloween_website_directory1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Select Category</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
      <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Article Title:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></p></td>
      <td width="67%" height="60%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="hallo_art_name" id="hallo_art_name"/>
        <span id="hallo_art_name1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Please enter the title of your Article</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
      <TD align="center" WIDTH="33%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><P><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Article Description:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></P></TD>
      <TD WIDTH="68%"><P>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<FONT SIZE="-2" FACE="Verdana" color="#FFCC66">&nbsp;Max 300 Characters<BR>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <TEXTAREA NAME="hallo_art_desc" id="hallo_art_desc" ROWS=5 COLS=33 WRAP="virtual"></TEXTAREA>
          <span id="hallo_art_desc1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Enter Description</span> <BR>
          </FONT> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<FONT SIZE="-2" FACE="Verdana" COLOR="#FFCC66"> Do not use "See web site" as
          your description.</FONT></P></TD>
    </TR>
    <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
      <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Article tags:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></p></td>
      <TD WIDTH="68%"><P><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana" color="#FFFFFF"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="hallo_art_tags" id="hallo_art_tags" value="" size=30>
          <span id="hallo_art_tags1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Article Tags</span> </FONT><FONT SIZE="-2" FACE="Verdana" color="#FFCC66"><br>
          <font> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Use a comma to separate each
          keyword.</font><BR>
          </FONT></P></TD>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
      <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Article Body:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></p></td>
      <td width="67%" height="60%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <textarea name="msgpost" id="msgpost" rows="10"/></textarea>
        <span id="msgpost1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Enter the Article content</span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
      <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Agree
          to our Submission
          Policy</font></p></Td>
      <TD WIDTH="68%"><P><FONT SIZE="-2" FACE="Verdana"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="policy" id="policy" VALUE="Y" />
          </FONT></P>
          <span id="chkbox" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Please check policy</span> 
          </TD>
    </TR>
    <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
      <td align="center" colspan="3" width="67%" height="60%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="add_article" id="add_article" value="Submit Article"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: take care of drop down PHP stuff.

Comment: Bharanikumar i put your code but i'm getting error in <tr style="width:60px; height:60px;">
      <td width="33%" height="60%" style="color:#FFFFFF;"><p align="center"><FONT SIZE="-1" FACE="Verdana">Article Body:<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span></FONT></p></td>
      <td width="67%" height="60%">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <textarea name="msgpost" id="msgpost" rows="10"/></textarea>
        <span id="msgpost1" style="color:#FF0000; display:none;">* Enter the Article content</span> </td>
    </tr> please help me

Comment: I'm getting the error message '* Enter the Article content' even after entering details in 'Article body' field. But validation of other fields are working clearly. i put your entire code without modification. Thanks for you nice response..

Comment: ok i could paste the code for your reference, where i should paste the code? please help me brother.. You gave me a nice code that worked moreover correctly excluding that error.. give me some ideas to clear that error, I'll be very thankful to you..

Comment: Bharanikumar, i fixed the error and your coding is correct. I only did that mistake.. Thank you :) :)